# Salesforce authentication failing even after extending same password by changing the setting on Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud

Salesforce token end point was working fine previously but recently it's password got expired. I asked SF team to extend the same password and after that I am able to login to SF portal and able to get SF access token using same password and security token by postman.

But when my prod application is making calls to SF it still gives same error message:

This session could not be mutually authenticated for use with the REST API","errorCode":"MUTUAL_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED"

Could you please help me that why after extending the same password (by changing some setting in sf) when the .net core application hit it, its getting same error message. Does it got cashed and SF service need to be restarted???

Comment: What OAuth flow (or SOAP login) is your .NET application using? Did you add the new Security Token to your stored credentials?

Comment: "mutual" sounds like you're using some kind of 2-way SSL? Do you have any expired certificates (in SF you can check in Setup -> Certificate and Key Management, in your .NET app no idea). Did you enable MyDomain recently maybe?